# What's the difference between несколько and сколько and некоторые in this context?

Tags: разница

What's the difference between несколько and сколько and некоторые in this context? For me, as a non Russian native speakers they look as synonym in this context, but I'm not sure about that.

For example:

> Там есть **сколько** яблоки.
>
> Там есть **несколько** яблоки.
>
> Там есть **некоторые** яблоки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first and last sentences are grammatically incorrect.
The first sentence should be a question (**"сколько"** = "**how many**"/"**how much**"):

> **Сколько там яблок?**

In the last sentence, the word "яблоки" must be in the plural, because "некоторые" requires the plural:

> **Там есть некоторые яблоки.**

But even in this version, this sentence looks clumsy. Native speakers would say:

> **Там есть кое-какие яблоки.**

or rather just:

> **Там есть яблоки.**

So only second sentence is fully correct and should be used in this case:

> **Там есть несколько яблок.**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Regards to яблок and яблоки it was a mistake, I edited it, because I want to focus on the adverbs that I asked about. May times I heard people say сколько not in interrogative sentences. For example: "дай мне пожалуйста сколько бананов". Is it considered a mistake and it should be used only in interrogative sentences? In addition, the dictionary translates the word "некоторые" as "some", so why is it not correct to ask ""дай мне пожалуйста некоторые бананов /деньги"?

Comment: "Дай мне пожалуйста сколько бананов" is not grammatical. Right form is: "Дай мне, пожалуйста, **несколько** бананов". Word **"некоторые"** in Russian is only one meaning of word **"some"**. **"Some"** may be translated as **"некоторый"** / **"некоторая"** / **"некоторое"** / **"некоторые"**, **"несколько"**, **"немного"**, **"кое-какие"**, etc. For example: "Дай мне, пожалуйста, **немного** бананов/денег".

Comment: Thank you. Well, I don't really understand when I should use "некоторые" and when I should use несколько. Because you said that "Там есть некоторые яблоки.". Isn't it?

Comment: Word **"некоторые"** in this context means **"some kind of"**. **"Некоторые яблоки"** = **"some kind of apples"**. **"Несколько яблок"** means **"some quantity of apples"**.

Comment: @Influx, you could possibly hear "дай мне сколько-то яблок", it's sooner несколько, than сколько.

Comment: Maybe I didn't notice the prefix "**не**" in the "некоторые" or I didn't notice the suffix **то** in сколько-то.